# Flink Schema vs Table Schema

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using Flink SQL API and I am a bit lost between all the 'schema' types : `TableSchema`, `Schema` (from `org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.Schema`) and `TypeInformation`.

A `TableSchema` can be created from a `TypeInformation`, a `TypeInformation` can be created from a `TableSchema` and a `Schema` can be created from a `TableSchema`

But it looks like a `Schema` cannot be converted back to `TypeInformation` or `TableSchema` (?)

Why is there 3 different type of objects to store the same kind of information ?

For example, let's say that I have a string Schema coming from an Avro schema file, and that I want to add a new field to it. To do so, the only solution I have found is :

```
String mySchemaRaw = ...;
TypeInformation<Row> typeInfo = AvroSchemaConverter.convertToTypeInfo(mySchemaRaw);
Schema newSchema = new Schema().schema(TableSchema.fromTypeInfo(typeInfo));
newSchema = newSchema.field("nexField",...);


// Need the newSchema as a TableSchema
```

Is this the normal way to use these objects ? (looks weird to me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TypeInformation` and `TableSchema` solve different things. `TypeInformation` is physical information how to ship a record class (e.g. a row or a POJO) from one operator to the other.

`TableSchema` describes the schema of a table independent of the underlying per-record type. It is similar to the schema part of a `CREATE TABLE name (a INT, b BIGINT)` DDL statement. In SQL one also doesn't define a table like `CREATE TABLE name ROW(a INT, B BIGINT)`. But it is true that schema and row type are related which is why converter methods are provided. The differences become bigger once concepts like `PRIMARY KEY` etc. are introduced.

`Schema` is the current way of specifying non-SQL concepts such as time attributes and field mappings.